# Question about current draw and wire guage of fluorescent lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have eight fluorescent T8 bulbs rated with a 32-W nominal power consumption. What is the nominal (rms?) and peak (inrush) current that they would be expected to draw on their 120-V circuit? Which wire gauge should be used for their wiring?

Comment: Usually on a 15 amp circuit(the common smallest), 14 gauge must be smallest gauge(larger can be used also).  A 15 amp circuit is good for a bit over 1200w up to 80% of 1800w(15x120)

Comment: You can get and use 10A breakers, but they are **rarely** seen/used, because of the minimum wire size being suitable for 15A circuits. Going further, 5A is not offered for my panel type, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our (USA) system, the 120V is the RMS value. The RMS value is .707 x peak voltage (170V).The peak to peak would be 340V.  These values have no meaning to general DIYer's. The meters we normally use measure RMS voltages and you won't see the peak numbers unless you use an oscilloscope.

Your fixtures will need 2.13 amps at 120V. The minimum wire wise allowed in household wiring is #14AWG and a 15 amp breaker.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack. Where did the 2.13 A come from? Is that per T8 or is that the total for each fixture with two T8s apiece?

Comment: @LazyTitanic That's 8 bulbs at 32 watts each .. divided by 120V = 2.13 Amps.

Comment: That... makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The **building wiring to the fixture** has to be 14 gauge copper, minimum, if you are in NEC/CEC covered parts of the world (as 120V would suggest.)

It does not matter (for NEC/CEC purposes) if the breaker is 10A rather than 15A nor if the fixture only uses 2.13 Amperes. Minimum size of building wiring is 14Ga copper, done and done. The wiring inside the fixture may be smaller, as its UL (or other NRTL) listing permits. The wiring that you run must be 14Ga or larger.

If the circuit has a 15A breaker, 14Ga is sufficient. If the circuit has a 20A breaker, 12Ga copper minimum is then required for all building wiring on that circuit.

*Historically there was a period when 12Ga/10Ga aluminum was also used, and the folks with those houses are still feeling the pain from that era.*

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, T8 fluorescent fixtures have electronic ballasts. They have inrush due to charging their capacitors, so on breakers and relays, the "tungsten" rating applies.  They do not have inductive "kick" on interrupt the way magnetic ballasts do, so "ballast" or "HID" ratings of equipment do not apply and are not needed.

In my experience with quality ballasts of ballast factor 1.0 and high PF, dual "32W" fluorescent fixtures draw 62 watts net.  So the ballasts aren't taking much.  So pencil in 0.25A per tube for running amperage.

### Circuits

You can't use arbitrary wire in North American (El NEC) countries.  It must be a wiring type and method listed in Chapter 3, such as *Article 334 NM Cable*.  The smallest allowable wire size is 14 AWG copper or 12 AWG aluminum, on a 15A breaker.  *Realistically, at that size, mineral value of the metal negligible and all the cost is in the insulation jacket. Smaller wire is pointless, and random electronics hookup wires are not allowed*.

NEC provides rules for lighting on 20A and 30A circuits. Smaller taps are allowed in industrial, but the cheaper wiring methods such as NM are not allowed in industrial; it's all stout stuff like AC whips or EMT.

### Managing inrush

Inrush is not a factor when designing with North American equipment and standards and rules, as this is already accounted for in design.  If you are dealing with provisioning current-limited sources like generator or inverter, then it matters, but we couldn't possibly speculate on the inrush of *any given particular ballast*.

I will suggest that *Rapid-Start* ballasts run the pre-heaters for a pre-set time (e.g. 0.5 seconds) before striking the lamp.  *Programmed-Start* ballasts run the pre-heaters for a variable time to produce ideal conditions for striking the lamp.  Therefore, if easing "inrush" is a concern, here are a couple of strategies:

- Use a mix of instant-start, rapid-start and programmed-start ballasts so the lamps strike at different times.
- Split the lights into multiple banks, each with a separate switch or breaker, so they aren't starting simultaneously. Better, position the switches far apart so the users must work one at a time.

Lastly, LED fixtures and LED retrofit "tubes" vary dramatically (and much of the stock offered for sale is just terrible quality)... but, they may have less or no inrush current.  I'm sticking with real fluorescent myself, at least where 4' and 8' T8 tubes are concerned. I convert oddball (pricey) tubes to LED.